# SQL Query get most wanted game details

Tags: sql, sql-server

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a295/1

I have a ms sql database inside visual studio 10, I need help with a query to get me the most wanted game from the favourites table along with the game cover_img from the games table.  I have got the query working with the first part:-

```
SELECT game_name, 
       game_platform, 
       Count(game_name) AS Expr1 
FROM   favourites 
GROUP  BY game_name, 
          game_platform 
HAVING ( Count(game_name) = (SELECT Max(mycount) AS Expr1 
                             FROM   (SELECT game_name, 
                                            Count(game_name) AS mycount 
                                     FROM   favourites AS Favourites_1 
                                     GROUP  BY game_name) AS derivedtbl_1) );
```

But I cant get the cover_img to match the max game from the games table, can someone please help me, this is what i have so far, but its not working:-

```
SELECT favourites.game_name, 
       favourites.game_platform, 
       games.cover_img, 
       Count(favourites.game_name) AS Expr1 
FROM   games 
       inner join favourites 
               ON games.name = favourites.game_name 
GROUP  BY favourites.game_name, 
          favourites.game_platform, 
          games.cover_img HAVING (Count(favourites.game_name) = (SELECT 
                                 Max(mycount) AS Expr1 
                                                                FROM 
                                 (SELECT game_name, 
                                         Count(game_name) AS mycount 
                                  FROM   favourites AS Favourites_1 
                                  GROUP  BY game_name) AS derivedtbl_1));
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik, it's SQL Server.

Comment: Do you have any kind of unique key on the games table?   The basic issue I believe is that you cannot group by a binary field in the database.

Comment: Yep Games table ID is game barcode and favourites ID is fav_ID both integers.  Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help for this question.

Comment: I am trying to put sql fiddle up but their website isn't working, can you guys get onto it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT TOP 1 f.game_name, f.game_platform, g.cover_img, 
       Count(f.game_name) as cnt
FROM   games g inner join
       favourites f
       ON g.name = f.game_name 
GROUP BY f.game_name, f.game_platform, g.cover_img
ORDER BY Count(f.game_name) desc;
```

Comment: This does get a cover_img but it the XBOX ONE, I need the game.name = g.name and game_platform = g.platform.  Would I just add another ON statement Gorden? Thanks

Comment: @Alexandria . . . I don't know what the `join` condition is between `games` and `favourites`.  If it requires two keys, then yes, you would add that to the `join` condition.

Comment: Hi Gordon I have created db on sqlfiddle and your query works but I just need to get the cover_img from the games table to match the top 1 game.  I have tried ON g.name = f.game_name, g.platform = f.game_platform but it doesnt work.  Would appreicate any help. Thanks http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a295/1

Comment: @Alexandria . . . The query had a typo (using the wrong table alias for `game_name`).  Is there an issue with the results it produces?

Comment: no issues it is perfect just I need to get the cover_img from the games table as well and Im not sure how to go about it, I need something like select max game name and platform from favourites table and get me the correpsonding cover_img from the games table.  Would I use a where? Select cover_img from games where f.game_name = g.name?  Thanks

Comment: @Alexandria . . . The query returns the cover image, so I am lost on what else you want to do.  If it is another question, perhaps you should ask another question.

Comment: Oh sorry I hadnt updated my query with your new edited one, really sorry but that one down to a blonde moment.  That is brilliant Gordon thanks very much :)

Comment: I have found a wee bug, if I have two games with the same name it will give me the wrong cover_img if it should be blur XBOX 360 but I have a blue XBOX 1 it will give me that because I need an g.platform = f.game_platform.  SOmething like this ON g.name = f.game_name and ON g.platform = f.game_platform but it doesnt work

Comment: Got it just had to add it into your query:- SELECT TOP (1) f.Game_name, f.Game_platform, g.Cover_img, g.Platform, COUNT(f.Game_name) AS cnt FROM Games AS g INNER JOIN Favourites AS f ON g.Name = f.Game_name AND g.Platform = f.Game_platform GROUP BY f.Game_name, f.Game_platform, g.Cover_img, g.Platform ORDER BY cnt DESC

Answer (score 2):

You can split your problem in smaller parts:

```
;
WITH    Games       AS
(
        SELECT  *
        FROM    (   VALUES
                    ('Pacman', 'Atari', 'A'),
                    ('Enduro', 'Atari', 'B'),
                    ('River Raid', 'Atari', 'C')
                ) AS X (Name, [Platform], cover_img)    
),      Favourites  AS
(
        SELECT  *
        FROM    (   VALUES
                    ('Pacman', 'Atari'),
                    ('Pacman', 'Atari'),
                    ('Pacman', 'Atari'),
                    ('Enduro', 'Atari')
                ) AS Y (game_name, game_platform)   
),      MostWanted  AS
(   --  Identify the most wanted game, per platform
        SELECT      game_name, game_platform, COUNT(*) Total,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                    (
                        PARTITION BY /*game_name,*/ game_platform
                        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                    ) [Order]
        FROM        Favourites
        GROUP BY    game_name, game_platform
)
SELECT  MostWanted.*, Games.cover_img
FROM    MostWanted
JOIN    Games       -- JOIN that with games table to get more details
    ON  MostWanted.game_name = Games.Name
WHERE   MostWanted.[Order] = 1  -- Only the first most wanted
```

Comment: THanks, I will give this a try, will this match game name with name from games table and Game_platform and Platform because at the moment I am getting the wrong platform? THanks

Comment: If you could add a data sample, that would help to do more tests.

Comment: I am trying to put sample up on sqlfiddle but I cant get onto website, can you?  Are do you know of a simlar site? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your first query will select the games you are looking for.

```
   SELECT game_name, 
           game_platform, 
           Count(game_name) AS Expr1 
    FROM   favourites 
    GROUP  BY game_name, 
              game_platform 
    HAVING ( Count(game_name) = (SELECT Max(mycount) AS Expr1 
                                 FROM   (SELECT game_name, 
                                                Count(game_name) AS mycount 
                                         FROM   favourites AS Favourites_1 
                                         GROUP  BY game_name) AS derivedtbl_1) );
```

Now what you need is a wrapper query to find all of the images associated with those games.

```
SELECT xx.game_name,xx.game_platform, games.cover_img
from
(SELECT game_name, 
        game_platform 
 FROM   favourites 
 GROUP  BY game_name, 
           game_platform 
 HAVING ( Count(game_name) = (SELECT Max(mycount) AS Expr1 
                              FROM   (SELECT game_name, 
                                      Count(game_name) AS mycount 
                                      FROM   favourites AS Favourites_1 
                                      GROUP  BY game_name) AS derivedtbl_1
                                     ) 
                             )
) xx
join games on games.game_name=xx.game_name 
     and games.game_platform=xx.game_platform
```

Give that a try.